# Можно ли имитировать нажатие клавиши не привязываясь к какому-либо элементу?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Знаю что есть такой метод:

```
email = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, 'xpath')
email.send_keys('text')
```

Но мне интересно, существует ли способ сымитировать нажатие клавиши не привязываясь к конкретному элементу с помощью библиотеки selenium? Я попробовал поискать но ничего не нашел.

Answer (score 0):

можно:

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.press("Enter")
```

это имитирует нажатие Enter.
Почитать документацию можно [здесь](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: имел ввиду с помощью библиотеки selenium

Answer (score 0):

В документации не сказано про нажатие клавиш без закрепления за элементом сайта. Можно использовать [Action Chains](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains), что напоминает имитацию нажатия.